# How to convert interger to time while the interger is actually time data but no separation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data that contains time data but in integer type and have no separation between the integer.
my data like = [91310, 101012, ...]  in fact it's suppose to be ["9:13:10", "10:10:12"]

how to convert that into time format

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your workings so far.

Comment: `import re;eval(re.sub(r'(\d{1,2})(\d{2})(\d{2})',r"'\1:\2:\3'",str(your_data)))`

Comment: When you say "convert that into time format", do you mean just adding the colons in the appropriate places, or do you mean that you want to create something like a `datetime.time` object?

Answer (score 0):

This method does not check whether the time is correct, ie hours<24, minutes and secods <60

```
a = [91310, 101012,94545]
def dd(x):
    n = str(x)
    return f'{n[:-4]}:{n[-4:-2]}:{n[-2:]}'
[dd(i)for i in a]
['9:13:10', '10:10:12', '9:45:45']
```

or using the regex:

```
eval(re.sub(r'(\d{1,2})(\d{2})(\d{2})',r"'\1:\2:\3'",str(a)))
 ['9:13:10', '10:10:12', '9:45:45']
```

Comment: Why are you running `eval` here? Surely you can just remove the extra quotation marks you have in your substitution instead? And regex seems like it's overkill for this problem, which can be handled by string slicing pretty trivially.

Comment: @Blckknght the eval is to take the result back to a list from a string. It is in no way related to the extra quotation in the replacement. Also for slicing you will have to run various for loops since you do not have a fixed value for the hours/minutes and seconds. Well, you should have run the code to see what it does, and see whether the eval is necessary or not. try it out before downvoting

Comment: Oh, I see you're converting the whole list of numbers to a single string. That still seems silly, but at least it makes a little more sense. It's still a pretty bad idea to use `eval` though. Using `ast.literal_eval` would be safer, but still, parsing a Python literal is massive overkill here, when you could just stick with a list of strings instead of making a string representation of the whole list.

Comment: @Blckknght. True true eval is an overkill. Thanks for  pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

Format the number with 5 (or 6) leading zeros and then take 2 character slices from the string:

```
[":".join(f"{n:05}."[-c:2-c] for c in [7,5,3]) for n in data]

# ['0:00:00', '0:00:05', '0:00:15', '0:02:35', '0:23:59', '1:35:46', '11:25:32']
```

If you're using this for a duration and you want to allow hours to go beyond 24 or even negative time:

```
data = [112532,3333759,-120503,-1234]

[":".join(f"{n:0{5+(n<0)}}."[-s:-e] for s,e in [(0,5),(5,3),(3,1)]) for n in data]

# ['11:25:32', '333:37:59', '-12:05:03', '-0:12:34']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple math operations to get the hours, minutes and seconds from your integer values. Then you can format them however you please (either into a string with appropriate colons, or into something like a `datetime.time` object).

```
import datetime

results = []
dt_results = []
for n in data:
    hours = n // 10000
    minutes = n // 100 % 100
    seconds = n % 100
    results.append(f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}')
    dt_results.append(datetime.time(hour=hours, minute=minutes, second=seconds))
```

If you don't want a leading zero on hours in the string results, remove the first `:02` from the format string. If you only want one of the results, you could pretty easily put the computations for the hours minutes and seconds inline into the format string or `datetime.time` call, and so turn the whole loop into a list comprehension:

```
results = [f'{n // 10000:02}:{n // 100 % 100:02}:{n % 100:02}' for n in data]
```